# Apple Trackpad Causing Long Keypress Events

Tags: keyboard, magic-trackpad

In the last day my Apple Magic Trackpad has started to cause long keypress events when I type on the keyboard.

For example, pressing 'a' in a browser menu bar will cause the accent popup to appear. Pressing 'cmd+t' will cause *multiple* tabs to open, and causes the 'File' menu to noticeably flicker as if being selected.

This even happens on the login screen. It is impossible to for to log in if trackpad is enabled, since each keypress produces multiple entries in my password.

Is anyone familiar with this situation and a potential fix?

Comment: The only time I've heard of similar issues is when the battery is going bad and swelling.  The battery sits under the trackpad and when it swells it causes trackpad problems.

Comment: This is the older trackpad, with removable batteries. I've replaced them already and the problem persists. Previous batters had no visible damage. This certainly is odd - it seems very counter that the trackpad would be reproducing keyboard events.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue - still not managed to find a fix - I only noticed by chance when the keyboard issue went away if I disconnected the magic trackpad.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. If you have a different question, ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can also add a [bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to get more users interested in the question. You can also read [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your chances on getting a good answer.